# How to reshape input data in RNN model for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

While making prediction with a trained model using new data, an error returned because the shape is different:

Here's the code:

```
print(test_data.shape)
print(df_2.shape)
```

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (126, 251) for Tensor 'input:0', which has shape '(?, 252, 1)'
```

The shape of training data and data used for prediction(needs to be reshaped):

```
(126, 252, 1)   #training data
(126, 60480)    #prediction data
```

I believe I'd tried something like this:

```
df_2 = np.reshape(df_2, (df_2.shape[0], df_2.shape[1], 1))
```

and I think there was something wrong. Should I do something like
`df_2 = df_2.reshape((test_inputs.shape[0], 252, 2))` or `x_train = df_2.reshape(df_2.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)`?

Other questions:

1)How can I change the shape of the input data?

2)What are the factors to consider when doing this? Or what is the rationale of changing shape and what happens when we change shape?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code sample. From the error it looks like you're trying to pass a 2-D tensor to a 3-D placeholder.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev please take a look at my edited question

Comment: RNNs need a 3D input. One dimension is the feature dimension; the second is determined by how many features you have in each training example; the third is the size of the batch, that is how many training examples at a time you are feeding the RNN. Have a look here: https://medium.com/@shivajbd/understanding-input-and-output-shape-in-lstm-keras-c501ee95c65e

Comment: @PatrizioG thanks for the article I've ran of quota, will check it later. I've edited the question, appreciate if you could shed some thought on the code